# Alternative to UNION clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to teach myself and better understand alternative methods to a UNION and discover when I can use joins.

As I'm playing with this I can't seem to get what I want without a UNION. Is it possible to write this in a single query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
  FROM table1 a, table2 b
 WHERE a.id = b.id
       AND a.ind IS NULL
       AND b.year >= '2017'
       AND b.code IN ('01','02','03')
       AND b.flag NOT IN ('F','L')
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
  FROM table1 a, table3 c
 WHERE a.id = c.id
       AND a.ind IS NULL
       AND c.area = 'MAIN'
       AND SYSDATE >= c.start
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance or help.

Comment: What you have now _is_ a single query, though it uses a union.  I think an alternative would involve joining all three tables together, but then the `WHERE` logic could get truly bufugly (if you don't know what that means, it means beyond ugly).

Comment: No need for `DISTINCT` in your queries as `UNION` will remove any duplicates.

Comment: You could have provided an SQL Fiddle with some test data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b on b.id = a.id AND b.year >= '2017'
     AND b.code IN ('01', '02', '03') AND b.flag NOT IN ('F', 'L') 
LEFT JOIN table3 c ON a.id = c.id and c.area = 'MAIN' and SYSDATE >= c.start
WHERE a.ind IS NULL
    AND ( b.id IS NOT NULL or c.id IS NOT NULL)
```

This is one of those things where the old obsolete `A,B` join syntax really shows it's age, when you have some conditions that must go in a specific `ON` clause and others that must go in the `WHERE` clause. It would be very difficult to write this query that way, and even harder to read and understand it later. Better to **always** write out the full `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, etc.

Comment: Two outer joins followed by a couple of "is not null" to turn them into inner joins again.  Why not?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille It's called an exclusion join. It's a common pattern that works quite well, and definitely does **not** just turn things back to an inner join again. The normal pattern would just check `IS NULL` instead of `IS NOT NULL`, but in this case doing the pattern twice with an `OR` the results are still correct.

Comment: An exclusion join!  Which proves one is never too old to learn.  I still think you're wasting time.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you see a distinct, resources have been wasted.

```
SELECT a.id
  FROM table1 a
  where a.ind IS NULL
    and (   exists (select null from table2 b
                      WHERE a.id = b.id
                        AND b.year >= '2017'
                        AND b.code IN ('01','02','03')
                        AND b.flag NOT IN ('F','L') )
         or exists (SELECT null FROM table3 c
                      WHERE a.id = c.id
                        AND c.area = 'MAIN'
                        AND SYSDATE >= c.startdt)
        )
```

Indexes on table2 (id,year,code,flag) and table3 (id,area,startdt) won't hurt performance.  Oracle 11gR2 did not allow me to have a column named "start".

Comment: I tend to use IN instead of EXISTS as it is shorter and usually easier to read. You must be careful and (almost) always use NOT EXISTS though.

Comment: @gpeche "(almost) always use NOT EXISTS though" ?

Comment: @gpeche you seem new to Oracle?  The exists had the advantiage to stop as soon as one row was found, while the in will create a view of all rows that satisfy the conditions, sort and distinct them.  Of course, with the cost based floptimizer, you're never sure.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - you seem to be too old to Oracle. What you describe changed a long time ago; at least since version 10, `IN` and `EXISTS` result in the same execution plan.

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille using Oracle since about 2001, it's been a looooong time since I have seen any difference in execution plans for IN vs EXISTS. Also, read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-may/o36asktom-099107.html:

`You would instead consider using either WHERE EXISTS or WHERE IN. (The cost-based optimizer [CBO] sees them as more or less equivalent—you might, too.)`

and

`In both cases, the optimizer would employ either a semi join, which you cannot specify but the optimizer may perform (it stops joining after the first hit)`

Comment: @Magnus read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists . Basically `IN` and `EXISTS` are "equivalent", but `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` behave differently in presence of `NULL`. In most cases, the "intuitive" behaviour is almost always the one provided by `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @gpeche I'm well aware. Different behavior for use in different situations.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this

```
select a.id
from table1 a
where
  a.ind is null and (
  a.id in (
    select b.id
    from table2 b
    where
    b.year >= '2017'
    and b.code IN ('01','02','03')
    and b.flag NOT IN ('F','L')  
  ) or
  a.id in (
    select c.id
    from table3 c
    where
    c.area = 'MAIN'
    and sysdate >= c.start
  )
)
```

`DISTINCT` + table joins can be rewritten as IN/EXISTS most of the times. In several databases it might even select a better execution plan (e.g: Oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if using Full outer join makes sense

```
with cte as (
select 1 as nu union 
select 2 as nu union 
select 3 as nu union 
select 4 as nu union 
select 5 as nu union 
select 6 as nu )
,cte2 as (
select 1 as nu union 
select 2 as nu union 
select 3 as nu )
,cte3 as (
select 7 as nu union 
select 8 as nu union 
select 9 as nu )
select coalesce(cte.nu,cte2.nu,cte3.nu)
from cte
full outer join cte2 on cte.nu = cte2.nu
full outer join cte3 on cte.nu = cte3.nu
```

Answer (score -2):

Please check if this works

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
  FROM table1 a, table2 b, table3 c
 WHERE (a.id = b.id
        OR a.id = c.id)
       AND a.ind IS NULL
       AND (( b.year >= '2017'
       AND b.code IN ('01','02','03')
       AND b.flag NOT IN ('F','L'))
       OR (c.area = 'MAIN'
       AND SYSDATE >= c.start))
```

Comment: This is a waste, you're joining table2 and table3 for no reason at all, causing a cartesian.